# copying pointer to member functions from a structure

Tags: c++

I have my code organized as following

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   typedef void (MyClass::Ptr2func)();
}

struct abc
{
    MyClass::Ptr2func ptr;
    bool result;
}

void main()
{
    MyClass myCls;
    abc  var;
    //here is a lot of decision making code and pointer initializations

    //I want to copy the pointer to function in another variable
    MyClass::Ptr2func tempPtr;
    tempPtr=var.ptr;
}
```

When I try to copy the `var.ptr` into `tempPtr` it gives me a compilation error that the argument list is missing.  Also it gives me compilation error on `myCls.*(var.ptr())`; Is there a precedence issue? I have tried using parenthesis but nothing works. I hope someone can help me out on this.

Thanks and regards,
Saba Taseer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that your typedef

```
typedef void (MyClass::Ptr2func)();
```

Is not defining a typedef for a pointer to member function, but for a member function type.  The typedef for a member function pointer would be

```
typedef void (MyClass::* Ptr2func)();
```

Notice the explicit pointer involved here.  The type

```
typedef void (MyClass::Ptr2func)();
```

is actually a typedef for the type of a **member function** inside of `MyClass` that takes no arguments and returns void.

As for your final question, the proper syntax for calling a pointer to a member function is (I believe)

```
(myCls.*var.ptr)()
```

Notice that you must parenthesize the expression `(myClass.*var.ptr)` before trying to call it as a function, since the code

```
myCls.*(var.ptr())
```

Means "dereference the pointer-to-member returned by `var.ptr()` relative to object `myCls`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1 since the original code does not compile, there's no teling what "the" problem is. Also it is a disservice to teach an utter novice about `goto` and `longjmp`. Or, as in this case, member function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef void (MyClass::Ptr2func)();
```

defines a function type. The `MyClass::` is completely extraneous in that definition; the final type is `void ()`. (Why? You're in MyClass, so `MyClass::` is treated as reinforcement that you want the typedef `Ptr2func` to belong to MyClass, not as a statement that you want the type to designate a member function.)

You want this:

```
typedef void (MyClass::*Ptr2func)();
```

which defines a pointer to a member function.

Comment: Are you sure that the `MyClass::` is extraneous?  I was under the impression that this is important and means "the type of a member function defined in `MyClass` that takes and returns `void`."

Comment: @templatetypedef: It means that, yes, but that type doesn't exist in C++, to the best of my knowledge. It has to be a *pointer* to a member function to exist as a type. I'm trying to find a reference to that in the standard…

Comment: Ah. Yes, herein lies the ambiguity. `MyClass::` is extraneous in the sense that `Ptr2func` itself (the typedef) is a member of `MyClass::`. If you move that typedef out of a class, you get this error: `error: typedef declarator cannot be qualified`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You're asking about compilation errors.

As I'm writing this your code does not have semicolong after each class definition.

Also, just about any other compiler than MSVC will react to `void main`; use standard `int main`.

As an utter beginner (making those kinds of mistakes) it's not a good idea to use member pointer.

Simply don't, but instead explain what you hoped to achieve by that.

Cheers & hth.